# Count all the NA values in one column of a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I looking to generate a table that takes a dataframe, counts all the NA values in each column then returns another dataframe that displays that count. I'm preferring to use dplyr tools here. I've gotten this far:

```
library(dplyr)
airquality %>% 
  group_by(Month) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum(. == 41, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

This returns a table that counts all the 41's. But if I modify it to NA's like so:

```
airquality %>% 
  group_by(Month) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum(. == "NA")))
```

This doesn't produce the desired output (described above). Any thoughts on how I can generate a table that counts all the NA values in each column?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
airquality %>% group_by(Month) %>%   summarise_each(funs(sum(is.na(.))))
```